# Is there an error in this proposition? Is every row of this diagram split? (from Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra)

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

At the end of this proposition, it is stated that the rows are split. However, not every short exact sequence of $R$-modules splits.

**Is there an error in this proposition?**

---

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

It should say the rows above the original sequence are split.